# What does am335x-pru0-fw do?

Tags: boot, audio

When I boot my BeagleBone Black I get the following error.
What exactly does this mean? What is `am335x-pru0-fw` meant to do?

Kernel Version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux arm 4.1.15-ti-rt-r40 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Fri Jan 8 09:44:57 UTC 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg` logs:

```
[   21.428541]  remoteproc1: Direct firmware load for am335x-pru0-fw failed with error -2
[   21.428582]  remoteproc1: failed to load am335x-pru0-fw
[   21.445653]  remoteproc1: Direct firmware load for am335x-pru0-fw failed with error -2
[   21.445674]  remoteproc1: request_firmware failed: -2
[   21.450762] pru-rproc 4a334000.pru0: rproc_boot failed
[   21.594364] pru-rproc: probe of 4a334000.pru0 failed with error -2
```

I am trying to integrate an adau1761 audio codec with BeagleBone Black. I created a sound card. But not able to play any sound. Does the above error related to this?

Comment: Do you have a link to that audio board? Does the driver / instalation software include a .dts file?

Comment: Something wants to load firmware into PRU0 (programmable real-time Unit 0), and it's failing. I can't tell from the error message whether "am335x-pru0-fw" is supposed to be the firmware file of the PRU device. But I would not think that an audio device would need the PRU (the .dts file would answer that question). Are there other devices or protocols that you're trying to use? like EtherCat or stepper motors? Those are the types of things that use the PRU.

Comment: Thank you! @Mark for the response. Ya I think this firmware is not required to play a sound from my audio codec because I could play some sound from it now. But noisy and high frequncy. For ref. my .dts file of the BeagleBone Black is: http://pastebin.com/5zc0TnR4
I use I2S for transfer of sound.

Comment: There is no mention of the PRU in your .dts file, so you are right - those PRU errors have nothing to do with your audio. Your audio problem might have to do with the audio clock rate. Between the BeagleBone-White and the BeagleBone-Black, an oscillator was added to support the audio on HDMI, and I remember something about it needing to be disabled to support other codecs. But the .dts should have taken care of it (unless it was meant for the White).

Comment: I think we have to disable HDMI to create other sound card. I use mono signals, so tdm-slots should be 1?

Answer (score 1):

### The Kernel log messages

Those kernel log messages are printed out by the remoteproc driver for PRUs (either by pruss or by pru_rproc) and the driver is trying to load the PRU firmware, that should ideally be located at /lib/firmware.

The PRUs should not interfere with the I2S bus that you are using. They are actually, not even getting booted up as there is no firmware to load onto them.

If you still want to get rid of those messages in the kernel log, just append your /etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf file with these lines :

```
blacklist pru_rproc 
blacklist pruss_intc
blacklist pruss
```

---

### Using I2S bus

I have not actually worked on I2s, but I can suggest you something on it based on what I have read :

Now, to use I2S bus, you need right mux mode on the right pin.

- First, you probably should not disable the HDMI. The Main processing unit actually transfers audio to the HDMI chip using this I2S bus. You are just using that bus in between that route from ARM to the HDMI chip. If you disable the HDMI, the ARM will probably not output the audio data onto the I2S bus, as for the ARM, HDMI is the only user.
- Please use this description to decide what pins you wish to use on the board.

[image]

- Once you know the pins you wish to use, use  [this sheet here](https://github.com/ZeekHuge/BeagleScope/blob/port_to_4.4.12-ti-r31%2B/docs/BeagleboneBlackP9HeaderTable.pdf) to decide the mux modes on those pins. I haven't seen your overlay source carefully, neither I am expert in it, but please do check twice that you have right mux modes in your overlay source.

You can then use something like :

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pins
```

to see the resultant mux on the pins.

### Edit :

- Please update to the latest kernel, that usually helps a lot. You can do this using apt-get and that will keep your configuration and data on beaglebone intact.
- Please use a non-rt version if you specifically do not want realtime kernel

Comment: To install the latest kernel version, see the 'Kernel development' part in [this post](https://www.zeekhuge.me/post/a_handfull_of_commands_and_scripts_to_get_started_with_beagleboneblack/)

Comment: Thanks alot @ZeekHuge for the reply. But according to the link: http://elinux.org/BBB_Audio_Cape_RevB_Getting_Started
Since the Audio Cape uses the same audio signal from the onboard HDMI interface, you need to disable the audio portion of the HDMI by edit the uEnv.txt at /boot/uboot. Add this line to the uEnv.txt file:

    optargs=capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI

Comment: I want to route the audio to my audio codec. Please guide.. Am I right?

Comment: OK so I read that link, but i still think disabling the HDMI would stop audio output, but not sure. 
That means you have the opportunity to explore it and let us know here.
Disabling and enabling these peripherals just takes some editing and a reboot. Probably hook up an oscilloscope onto the clock pin and first disable and then enable the HDMI port. That will clear the doubt.
[This link](https://www.zeekhuge.me/post/ptp_blinky/) has a section on disabling HDMI, revert it and HDMI will be enabled again.
Note : Make sure you are not on a too old kernel version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think Enabling or disabling both does not effect the audio coming out. I have the audio signal on the I2S bus.. Only problem is, it is not playing properly in the audio codec output. There are lot of noise.